# How can I add bookmarks to Google Collections from desktop browser?

Tags: google-search

[This page says](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9217379?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) that ([for some inexplicable reason](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/01/22/google-finally-lets-you-share-and-collaborate-on-bookmarks-hides-the-feature-somewhere-you-wont-find/)) you can only add images and job searches (though they forgot to mention that you can save map locations from as well) from a desktop browser to your Google Collections (formerly "Saved Pages,") but on a mobile device you can add a bookmark from any site to your collections.

There must be a way around this, outside of running an Android emulator on a desktop computer. Google had an official Chrome extension to allow this but killed it [for some inexplicable reason](https://9to5google.com/2018/07/22/google-kills-save-to-google-chrome-material-theme/). How can I add a regular URL to [my Google Collections page](https://google.com/save) from a desktop computer?